# Display Data From 2 Table in GridView Asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

i have Two Table Like This

```
Request     Example          UniTerm    Example

St_Code     1                 Id       1        2
St_Name     FirstStudent     Term      96-97    95-94
St_Family   FirstFamily
```

and i have a Grid View contain St_Code,Name,Family and Term
now the problem is i want to display all records of the student with the Just Last Record Term field in Term table 
i need gridview data like below

```
1 FirstStudent FirstFamily 96-97
```

show last record of the Term table and all of the Student table Records

i tried this SQL Code to select them

```
SELECT Request.St_Code, Request.St_Name, Request.St_Family, UniTerm.Term FROM Student CROSS JOIN UniTerm ORDER BY UniTerm.Term DESC
```

its ok but shows all of the records in UniTerm table i need just last one!

thanks in advance

Comment: Please review [Ask] and [MCVE].  Show the code that declares the tables involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update your query

**SELECT** Request.St_Code, Request.St_Name, Request.St_Family, UniTerm.Term FROM Student CROSS JOIN UniTerm ORDER BY **UniTerm.Id  DESC**